# How can I get use the boolean value from jtable to make the progress bar work?

Tags: java

```
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author awseo
 */
public class GUI_To_Do_List extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form GUI_To_Do_List
     */
    int task=0;
    DefaultTableModel model;
    public GUI_To_Do_List() {
        initComponents();
        model=(DefaultTableModel) List.getModel();
    }
    public static void Dosomething() {
                new GUI_To_Do_List().setVisible(true);
            }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        Input_Dialog = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        Cancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Ok = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Input_Task = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Type = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Priority = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Task_Text = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        School = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Home = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Other = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Priority_Number = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        Task = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Edit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Delete = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Exit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Task_List = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        List = new javax.swing.JTable();
        TaskProgress = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        Refresh = new javax.swing.JButton();

        Input_Dialog.setTitle("Task");
        Input_Dialog.setLocation(new java.awt.Point(300, 120));
        Input_Dialog.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 205));

        Cancel.setText("Cancel");
        Cancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CancelActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Ok.setText("OK");
        Ok.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                OkActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Input_Task.setText("Task");

        Type.setText("Type");

        Priority.setText("Priority");

        buttonGroup1.add(School);
        School.setText("School");
        School.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SchoolActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        buttonGroup1.add(Home);
        Home.setText("Home");

        buttonGroup1.add(Other);
        Other.setText("Others");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout Input_DialogLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(Input_Dialog.getContentPane());
        Input_Dialog.getContentPane().setLayout(Input_DialogLayout);
        Input_DialogLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            Input_DialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(Ok, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(Cancel))
                    .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(Input_Task, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(Type, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(Priority, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(Task_Text)
                            .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                    .addComponent(Priority_Number, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(School, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(Home)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(Other)
                                .addGap(0, 126, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        Input_DialogLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            Input_DialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, Input_DialogLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Input_Task)
                    .addComponent(Task_Text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(Type)
                    .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(School)
                        .addComponent(Home)
                        .addComponent(Other)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Priority)
                    .addComponent(Priority_Number, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(Input_DialogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Ok)
                    .addComponent(Cancel))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(new java.awt.Point(300, 120));

        Task.setText("New Task");
        Task.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                TaskActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Edit.setText("Edit");
        Edit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                EditActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Delete.setText("Delete");
        Delete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                DeleteActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Exit.setText("Exit");
        Exit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ExitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        List.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Index", "Task", "Type", "Priority", "Status"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Boolean.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, true, true, true, true
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        List.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                ListMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        Task_List.setViewportView(List);

        TaskProgress.setString("Please work");
        TaskProgress.setStringPainted(true);

        Refresh.setText("Refresh");
        Refresh.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                RefreshActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(Task)
                        .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                        .addComponent(Edit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                        .addComponent(Delete)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(Refresh)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 8, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(Exit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(TaskProgress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(Task_List, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(Task_List, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 384, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(TaskProgress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Task)
                    .addComponent(Edit)
                    .addComponent(Delete)
                    .addComponent(Exit)
                    .addComponent(Refresh))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void DeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        if(List.getSelectedRow() != -1)
            model.removeRow(List.getSelectedRow());
        task--;
        fill();
    }                                      

    private void EditActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        if(List.getSelectedRow() != -1)
            Edit();
    }                                    

    void Edit(){
        Input_Dialog.setVisible(true);
        String tmp="";
        Task_Text.setText(model.getValueAt(List.getSelectedRow(),1).toString());
        tmp=model.getValueAt(List.getSelectedRow(),2).toString();
        if(tmp.equals("School"))
            School.setSelected(true);
        else
            School.setSelected(false);
        if(tmp.equals("Home"))
            Home.setSelected(true);
        else
            Home.setSelected(true);
        if(tmp.equals("Other"))
            Other.setSelected(true);
        else
            Other.setSelected(false);
        Priority_Number.setValue(Integer.parseInt(model.getValueAt(List.getSelectedRow(),3).toString()));
    }
    private void ExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        System.exit(0);
    }                                    

    private void OkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        String temp="";
        if(School.isSelected()){
            temp="School";
        }
        if(Home.isSelected()){
            temp="Home";
        }
        if(Other.isSelected()){
            temp="Other";
        }
        model.addRow(new Object[]{1,Task_Text.getText(),temp,Priority_Number.getValue(),false});
        Input_Dialog.dispose();
        task++;
        fill();
    }                                  

    private void SchoolActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void CancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        Input_Dialog.dispose();
    }                                      

    private void TaskActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
       Input_Dialog.setVisible(true);
       Task_Text.setText("");
       School.setSelected(false);
       Home.setSelected(false);
       Other.setSelected(false);
       Priority_Number.setValue(1);
    }                                    

    private void ListMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
       if(evt.getClickCount() == 2)
           Edit();
    }                                 

    private void RefreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        fill();
    }                                       

    public void fill(){
        int row= List.getRowCount();
        int h = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while(h<=row){
            Boolean chk = (Boolean) List.getValueAt(h,5);
            if (chk==true){
                count++;
            }
            h++;
        }
        TaskProgress.setValue((count/task)*100);
        System.out.println(task);
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI_To_Do_List.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI_To_Do_List.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI_To_Do_List.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI_To_Do_List.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new GUI_To_Do_List().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton Cancel;
    private javax.swing.JButton Delete;
    private javax.swing.JButton Edit;
    private javax.swing.JButton Exit;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Home;
    private javax.swing.JDialog Input_Dialog;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Input_Task;
    private javax.swing.JTable List;
    private javax.swing.JButton Ok;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Other;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Priority;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner Priority_Number;
    private javax.swing.JButton Refresh;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton School;
    private javax.swing.JButton Task;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar TaskProgress;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane Task_List;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Task_Text;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Type;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is the full code. I am using Netbeans so most of the GUI was defined there including the JTable and the Progress Bar.

```
     public void fill(){
        int row= List.getRowCount();
        int h = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while(h<=row){
            Boolean chk = (Boolean) List.getValueAt(h,5);
            if (chk==true){
                count++;
            }
            h++;
        }
        TaskProgress.setValue((count/task)*100);
        System.out.println(task);
    }
```

This is the code for changing the Progress bar depending on if Status is true or not. However, the progress bar doesn't respond to any changes.

Comment: I recommend taking this site's [tour] and reading the various pages in the [help], particularly [ask]. And please.... [format code as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: What exactly does the `List` `JTable` contain? What do the boolean values indicate? Instead of the full code, post only the relevant snippets.

Comment: Depending on your requirements it's probably enough to just rewrite the calculation: `TaskProgress.setValue(100*count/task);`.